# How to make a function in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a mat-table with 6 columns. In 5th column it shows the status of Job i.e Completed,Running or Pending.
I have created two buttons i.e Stop and Re-Run.
I want to write function that if job is completed then Stop button should be disabled and re-run should be enabled which means that the user should be able to re-run the completed job and if job is executing or pending(waiting to execute) then Stop button should be  enabled and re-run should be disabled which means that the user should be able to stop the running Job.
Can someone help me ?

I have created a sample [stackblitz here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-progressbar-autocomplete-bavr9a)

HTML Code:

```
<div class="main-content">
<mat-toolbar>
    <mat-progress-bar
        mode="indeterminate"
        class="mat-progress-bar"
        color ="primary"
    >
    </mat-progress-bar>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button
    mat-icon-button
    (click)="stop_exec_job()"
    matTooltip="Stop Executing the Job"
>
    <!-- Edit icon for row -->
    <i class="material-icons" style="color:red"> stop </i>
</button>

</mat-toolbar>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h5 class="title">Job Execution Stats</h5>
    </div>

    <mat-table [dataSource]="jobExecutionStat">
        <!-- Id Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.id }} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="exec_date">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                Execution Date
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
                >{{ element.exec_date }}
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Weight Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="curr_time_period">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                Current Time Period
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
                >{{ element.curr_time_period }}
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Symbol Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="prev_time_period">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                Previous Time Period
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
                >{{ element.prev_time_period }}
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"
                >{{ element.status }}
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index = index">
                <button
                    mat-icon-button
                    (click)="stop_exec_job()"
                    matTooltip="Stop Executing the Job"
                >
                    <!-- Edit icon for row -->
                    <i class="material-icons" style="color:red"> stop </i>
                </button>
                <!-- Delete icon for row -->
                <button
                    class="stop_btn"
                    mat-icon-button
                    color="#b71c1c"
                    (click)="re_run_job()"
                    matTooltip="Re-Run the Job"
                >
                    <i class="material-icons" style="color:green">
                        cached
                    </i>
                </button>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row
            *matHeaderRowDef="jobExecStatDisplayedColumns"
        ></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: jobExecStatDisplayedColumns">
        </mat-row>
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

Typescript Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MatTableDataSource } from "@angular/material";
import { GlobalAppSateService } from '../../services/globalAppSate.service';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
import { SnakBarComponent } from '../custom-components/snak-bar/snak- 
bar.component';
@Component({
selector: "app-job-execution-screen",
templateUrl: "./job-execution-screen.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./job-execution-screen.component.scss"]
})
export class JobExecutionScreenComponent implements OnInit {
stop_btn: boolean = true;
re_run_btn: boolean = true;


jobExecStatDisplayedColumns = [
    "id",
    "exec_date",
    "prev_time_period",
    "curr_time_period",
    "status",
    "actions"
];

jobExecutionStat = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);
constructor(private dataService: DataService, public globalAppSateService: 
GlobalAppSateService, private snakbar: SnakBarComponent ) {

}
ngOnInit() {
    const project = JSON.parse(this.dataService.getObject("project"));
    if (project != null) {
        this.globalAppSateService.onMessage(project);
    }
}


stop_exec_job() {

}
re_run_job() {

}
}
const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
{
    id: 1,
    exec_date: "17-01-2016",
    prev_time_period: "2016-04,2016-05,2016-06",
    curr_time_period: "2016-08",
    status: "Completed"
},
{
    id: 2,
    exec_date: "17-01-2017",
    prev_time_period: "2017-04,2017-05,2017-06",
    curr_time_period: "2017-08",
    status: "Running"
},
{
    id: 3,
    exec_date: "27-07-2017",
    prev_time_period: "2017-45,2017-46,2017-47",
    curr_time_period: "2018-01,2018-02",
    status: "Pending"
},
{
    id: 4,
    exec_date: "17-10-2018",
    prev_time_period: "2017-30,2017-31,2017-32",
    curr_time_period: "2018-01,2018-02",
    status: "Completed"
},
{
    id: 5,
    exec_date: "21-01-2018",
    prev_time_period: "2016-01,2016-02,2016-03,2016-04",
    curr_time_period: "2016-52",
    status: "Pending"
},
{
    id: 6,
    exec_date: "17-01-2018",
    prev_time_period: "2017-31,2017-32,2017-33,2017-34",
    curr_time_period: "2017-52",
    status: "Running"
}
];
export interface Element {
id: number;
exec_date: string;
prev_time_period: string;
curr_time_period: string;
status: string;
}
```

For some reason stop and cached are icons and in my visual studio i can see icons but in stackblitz I can't convert them to icons.
Just for reference stop in red color is Stop and cached in green color is re-run

Comment: What is your question exactly? Icon's not showing or buttons not working or state not persisting?

Comment: buttons not working.I have created a function stop_exec_job but i don't know how to write a function that if status is Completed then re-run button should be enabled. Icons not showing is for SOF users not to get confused when looking at stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable buttons in your table you will have to use `disabled` attribute and make a check with your element status.

```
[disabled]="element.status === 'Completed'" // The button will be disabled if status is Completed
[disabled]="element.status === 'Running'" // Disabled if status is Running
```

Considering your criteria, your Stop button will look like this:

```
<button
    [disabled]="element.status === 'Completed'"
    mat-icon-button
    (click)="stop_exec_job()"
    matTooltip="Stop Executing the Job"
>
    <!-- Edit icon for row -->
    <i class="material-icons" style="color:red"> stop </i>
</button>
```

And your ReRun button will be like:

```
 <button 
       [disabled]="element.status === 'Running'"
       class="stop_btn"
       mat-icon-button
       color="#b71c1c"
       (click)="re_run_job()"
       matTooltip="Re-Run the Job"
          >
           <i class="material-icons" style="color:green">
                            cached
           </i>
       </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `disabled` to disable the button or `*ngIf` to remove it from the DOM completely.

```
<button mat-icon-button [disabled]="isRunning" (click)="stop_exec_job()" matTooltip="Stop Executing the Job"></button>

<button mat-icon-button [disabled]="!isRunning" (click)="stop_exec_job()" matTooltip="Stop Executing the Job"></button>
```

Update the state based on what action was executed. Be sure to set the correct initial state as well.

```
isRunning: boolean = false;

stop_exec_job() {
  this.isRunning = false;
}

re_run_job() {
  this.isRunning = true;
}
```

Comment: I want this thing but based on a condition. If the status column of my table is  completed then stop_btn should be enabled or else if its pending then it should be disabled

Comment: @saad - your stackblitz is not the same at all as the code in your question. If you want a single status used to disable your button you can do the following. You can tailor it further as you see fit, the concept remains the same.

Comment: I want something like this but what your code does is if i click on it the stop button disappears and if i click on re-run then re-run button disappears

Comment: @saad - see my first line `Use disabled to disable the button or *ngIf to remove it from the DOM completely.` You are probably using `*ngIf` if the button is no longer visible.

Comment: No i am using your updated answer .ie disabled and not *ngIf